# printf vs putchar - different output

Tags: c

I have this simple code (trying to do an exercise in KandR):-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 int c = EOF;

 while(c=(getchar() != EOF)){
   printf("%d",c);
 }

return 0;
}
```

When i run this and enter any character (a single character), i get the output as 11. If i enter multiple characters for example 'bbb' i get the output as 1111. I understand that i have explicitly added brackets to give precendence to the condition check of getchar() != EOF which should either result in 1 or 0. But i don't understand why am i getting multiple 1's.

Another case is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 int c = EOF;

 while(c=(getchar() != EOF)){
   putchar(c);
 }

return 0;
}
```

No matter which character i enter, i always get the output as a square box with 1's and 0's in it (shown at the bottom of the screenshot below)

[image]

1) In the first case, why is the output printing more than 1 1's?

2) Why isn't the output of case 2 same as case 1?

Comment: You're while loop is wrong. Try `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`

Comment: For putchar to print a '1', you'd have to send it the Ascii value for 1  (49 decimal) not the integer 1.  You have a value vs. character problem.

Comment: Your description of the second output is misleading. Both variants of the code will typically produce absolute the same line formatting, i.e. there will not be any special "boxes" in the second example. The only difference is that the first example uses `1` as output character, while the second example uses `\x1` as output character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until unless you press `EOF`, `(getchar() != EOF)` will return `true` which assigns `1` to `c`. That's why you are getting output always as `11`, first `1` for the character you entered and second `1` is for `\n` passed to the input buffer on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Similarly in case of `putchar` it prints the character corresponding to the  returned value `1` which is non-printable (printable characters start from `32`) and you will get some weird output, one for input character and another for `\n`.

Now change the parentheses in conditional expression to

```
while( (c=getchar()) != EOF ){...}
```

Now it will work as it should but will give you two ASCII code in first case (one for `\n`).

Comment: So this putchar processes characters until a \n is received, thereby marking the end of stream? Did i understand this correctly?

Comment: `\n` is also a character but non-printable and `putchar` simply put it to your screen.

Comment: In the second case, if i change the putchar line to putchar((char)c); It also does not print the expected output i.e. 1. Why?

Comment: `1` is ASCII for non-printable character. Casting `c` to `char` would not help you here. You will get some weird thing.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) In the first case, why is the output printing more than 1 1's?

Because you are looking for an `EOF`. In order to send your program `EOF` from the keyboard, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

> 2) Why isn't the output of case 2 same as case 1?

Because `%d` produces a decimal representation of the character code, while `putchar` produces the character itself. For example, if you print `'A'` using `printf`'s `%d` format, you would see `65` - ASCII code of the uppercase character `A`. On the other hand, if you print it using `putchar`, you would see character `A` itself.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/9y0GFl)

Comment: Ctrl+Z sends a suspend signal, not an EOF